# Is "the" required in the mentioned context?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles

Is "the" required in the following context?

> What did cause this problem? **The** suspects are A and B.

We are talking about suspects for the first time, so it doesn't need "the". But, as "suspects" are known in the author's mind, should we use "the" for it?

Comment: One would say either "What caused this problem?" or "What did cause the problem?", never "What did cause this problem?" which is ungrammatical. And, yes, you do need the definite article in front of suspects.

Comment: @ohwilleke “What did cause this problem?” is not ungrammatical; it just doesn't fit this context. It's emphatic, and there's no indication that any emphasis is required here.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should put it there. Because you are talking about a **specific** thing **not a general** idea. It doesn't matter whether you use it for the first time or not. Consider:

> I couldn't live without **music**. (We are talking generally)
>   The film wasn't good, but I liked **the music**. (We are talking specifically)

And also things in author's mind would be revealed by asking questions.

Comment: So leaving out the article 'the' makes the sentence sound abrupt.